# How do I put greek letters with subscripts and as functions in axis labels for persp in R

Tags: r

I want to have greek letters pi(t) on z axis, kappa on x axis and sigma_0. Here is what i tried. I have tried unicode but it wont work. Here is my code.

```
library(plot3D)
#check up unicode for greek letters for persp function which doesnt use simbols
T <- 40
r <- 0.02
rho <- -0.6
theta <- 0.3
w <- 100
w0 <- 20
P <- 1.0
a <- 1.0
gamm <- 0.05    
t <- 10

prop <- function(k, sigma0){
  theta * (w - w0 - T) * exp(-r * (T - t)) * 
    (k + theta * sigma0 * rho * exp(-(k + theta * sigma0 * rho * (T - t)))) / 
    (gamm * (k + theta * sigma0 * rho) * (w - w0 - t))
}

k <- seq(5, 10, length= 10)
sigma0 <- seq(0.1, 0.9, length= 10)

z <- outer(k, sigma0, prop)

persp3D(k, sigma0, z, theta = 30, phi = 0, border = "black", 
      ticktype = "detailed", xlab = "k",ylab = "sigma_0", 
      zlab ="pi(t)")
text3D(2, -5, 0, labels = expression(sigma[0]), add = TRUE, adj = 1)
```

Also pos (2, -5, 0) in text3D is not being displayed.

Comment: `text3D` works perfectly with `expression`, as long as you give it coordinates included in the plot area. Try `persp3D(k, sigma0, z, theta = 30, phi = 0, border = "black", ticktype = "detailed", xlab = "k",ylab = "", zlab =""); text3D(10.5, 0.4, 1.88, labels = expression(sigma[0]), add = TRUE, adj = 1); text3D(4, 0.2, 1.905, labels = expression(pi(t)), add = TRUE, adj = 1)`

Comment: @Cath, how do i choose these coordinates. How do i know the area of the plot.

Comment: you look at the values of the 3 axes?

Comment: @Cath, I mean what is the orientation used by R. Where is x, y,z on my screen. Ok is there a document explaining this?

Comment: if you use the default angles, x is "in front of you" and goes left-> right, y goes front-back and z bottom-top but you can see that if you look at the xlab, ylab and zlab which you defined in your persp call. and as for the doc, you can start with `?persp`...